# .htaccess | Rewrites with pages

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

So I'm adjusting the URLs on a site I'm working on and I'm having some trouble with a couple of variables being passed in the URL.

```
mylighting.com/bath-fixture-c-13.html?osCsid=u2qj8o9rvjn0p5pa7p8npuhs54
RewriteRule ^bath-fixture bath-fixture-c-13.html?id=$1
```

So this Rewrite works perfect as the page that comes up is `mylighting.com/bath-fixture`

Now unfortunately on that page there are several other items to view and I'm having some trouble with the page variable. I think I have the code correct but every time I try to go to the correct page it doesn't seem to work.

```
http://mylighting.com/bath-fixture-c-13.html?page=2&id=u0hnumfus6gjhjc45av36663m3
RewriteRule ^bath-fixture/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ bath-fixture-c-13.html?page=$1&id=$2
```

So I thought I had this correct but apparently not. I would like the output to be 
`mylighting.com/bath-fixture/2` for the second page.

Unfortunately with that code in the .htaccess, every time I input that URL it takes me to the first page of the category and not the second like it should.

Comment: What is the URL do you want to see in the browser and what do you want to internally rewrite to?

Comment: I want to see mylighting.com/bath-fixture/2 as the output in the browser.

Comment: Based on your comments below, and your statements above, you want to use mylighting.com/bath-fixture/2 as the input and have the content of mylighting.com/bath-fixture-c-13.html?id= served, without a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have misunderstood the format of the RewriteRule.  The first one is working by accident.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^bath-fixture-c-13.html bath-fixture/%1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^bath-fixture-c-13.html bath-fixture/ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

The first argument to RewriteRule is the regex to match against the requested URL.  The second argument is the URL to send as a Redirect to the user, so they end up at your desired URL instead.  Because you want to parse the QUERY_STRING I believe you need to use a RewriteCond.   If you are doing this for SEO purposes do not forget to add the [R=301].

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

If you are trying to go the other direction then you need the following.

```
RewriteRule ^bath-fixture/$ bath-fixture-c-13.html [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^bath-fixture/([0-9]+) bath-fixture-c-13.html?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you can clarify your desired inputs and outputs you will get correct answers much more quickly.

Comment: I'm a little confused now, cause after adding the parameters how you specified. I'm back to the beginning and now the URL is not working.

Comment: Perhaps your question is a little confusing.  It is unclear if you are trying to go from an input of http://mylighting.com/bath-fixture-c-13.html?page=2&id=u0hnumfus6gjhjc45av36663m3 to http://mylighting.com/bath-fixture/2  or vice versa.  The rules above go this direction from complex input to simple output.  If however you are trying to go from simple user request to complex internal path, they are backwards.

Comment: As it is the URLS output as this: mylighting.com/bath-fixture-c-13.html?id=Qsd443553213Dg and I am converting them to mylighting.com/bath-fixture. The problem I'm having is not with the first instance but with this instance where the url is: mylighting.com/bath-fixture-c-13.html?page=2&id=!sd556344778545Dg and Im trying to convert it to mylighting.com/bath-fixture/2

Comment: So the first instance is working because both cases start with bath-fixture, so that rule matches, but that rule is also always serving the content of bath-fixture-c-13.html.  If that is your intent then you are starting with an input of /bath-fixture/ and want an output of /bath-fixure-c-13.html...  In that case my edits above should help.  In your first rule you use $1 which refers to the first set of () which there are none so it is blank.  This is unnecessary and confusing.  In your second sample you have a $2 with only one set of () in the rule, also blank and unnecessary.

Comment: Really what it comes down to is are you trying to provide pretty URLs for an ugly backend, or are you trying to make legacy ugly urls work with a new pretty backend.

Comment: Ah!!! I got you now. Thanks so much for that info Aaron, I got it up and working. I really appreciate the help and sticking through the confusion, it is much appreciated.